# Cannot POST data to URL using Pythons requests library from external file

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to POST data to a URL using Pythons requests library.

If I try and do this by setting a multiline string variable which contains the post data in my script, everything works fine.

If I try to read in an external file with the same data in, the request fails on the application server I'm posting to, because it thinks there is invalid XML.

For example:

This **works**

```py
starturl="http://myserver.example.com/location/where/I/post"
username=user
password=mypassword

# Set the XML data
xmldata="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
(Lots more xml)
"""

# POST the job data

session = requests.Session()

request = session.post(starturl, auth=(username,password), data=xmldata, headers=post_headers)
```

Server side application processes the request just fine. However, if the only change I make is to read the xml data from an external file, this no longer works.

**This does not work**

```py
xmlfile="/path/to/my/xmldata.xml"
xmldata = open(xmlfile,'r')


session = requests.Session()
request = session.post(start_url, auth=(username,password), data=xmldata.read(), headers=post_headers)
```

The server side application, then errors with:

```
"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"
```

When inspecting with wireshark I can see there is a difference in the request body of my POST. Three little dots are appearing from somewhere

**When it works:**

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Authorization: Basic c3BvdGFkbTpQQHNzdzByZA==

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**When it fails:**

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Authorization: Basic c3BvdGFkbTpQQHNzdzByZA==

...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I'm not sure what's causing the 3 leading dots to appear in the request body. I've inspected the source XML file, tried stripping newlines from it. Nothing seems to do the trick?

Comment: Well, you can simply post requests with data from file `xmldata` without reading it. See [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads) part of documentation. Just use `request = session.post(starturl, auth=(username,password), data=xmldata, headers=post_headers)` where `xmldata` is opened file. However I am not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Try with binary read: `xmldata = open(xmlfile,'rb')` As long as error can not be reproduced, there will be no exact answer.

Comment: It's impossible to debug without having your xml file, but you maight have a BOM at the beginning of your file. Microsoft is notably (in)famous for insisting on putting useless BOM on all utf-8 files. You can check the first three characters of your file for the `codecs.BOM_UTF8` sequence (`'\xef\xbb\xbf'`) and strip it out if it's there.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You were right! The XML file was copied from a Windows system and the Python script was running on a Linux system. After careful inspection of the source, a BOM was indeed present. Removing it solves the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: @AdityaK glad I could help. I allowed myself to repost the comment as an answer, feel free to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell for sure without having your xml file, but you might have a BOM at the beginning of your file. Microsoft is notably (in)famous for insisting on putting useless BOM on all utf-8 files.

You can check the first three characters of your file for the codecs.BOM_UTF8 sequence ('\xef\xbb\xbf') and strip it out if it's there.